# AngularJS: how to call recursive function with a delay?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I have such function:

```
$scope.getContactsByScroll = function() {
  $scope.pageN = $scope.pageN + 1;
  if (!$scope.allDataIsLoaded){
    fetchMyDataService.getContactsByScrollService($scope.pageN).then(function(response) {
      if (response.length === 0){
        $scope.allDataIsLoaded = true;
      }
      else if (response.length !== 0 && !$scope.allDataIsLoaded){
        angular.forEach(response, function(el) {
          $scope.contacts.push(el);
        });
        //$timeout(function() {
          $scope.getContactsByScroll();
        //}, 2000);
      }
    }).catch(function() {
      $scope.allDataIsLoaded = true;
    });
  }
};
```

but it call themselves several times even, if `$scope.allDataIsLoaded` is `false`

when i set `timeout`: all works like a charm. But i don't think that this is a good solution. How can i delay my function without a timeout?

Comment: Why do you think $timeout isn't a good solution? It seems like the most logical solution to me.

Comment: timeout is a pretty good solution...

Answer (score 0):

Using timeout in asynchronous functions is not a good idea:

1. If your request time is longer then timeout, then you'll get unnecessary requests.
2. If your timeout is bigger then request time, then you'll get unnecessary lags.

You should use promise chain for reqursive requests. Try something like this:

```
var asyncService = function ($timeout)
    {
        var someData = 10;
        var service =
            {
                FetchData: function (someArray)
                {
                    someData++;
                    //timeout here is just for demonstration of async request
                    return $timeout(function () { return someData }, 1000)
                        .then(function (result)
                        {
                            return service.ProcessData(result, someArray);
                        });
                },
                ProcessData: function (data, someArray)
                {
                    console.log(data);
                    if (data == 15)
                    {
                        return someArray;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        someArray.push(data)
                        return service.FetchData(someArray);
                    }
                }
            };
        return service;
    }
```

Here's a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/WFSUwab4VmaxfFPf1r3D) with demonstration